# Amber power light on Dell dekstop

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, dell-optiplex

I've got a Dell Optiplex 745.  When I turn it on at the power socket, the power light is amber. When I press the power button, the fan starts (loudly!), and the power light remains amber.  The motherboard light is also a solid amber.

I know that this means that either the power supply or the motherboard is faulty - but I don't know which! Is it worth changing the power supply, or is it much more likely that the motherboard has failed?

Comment: Could also be CPU. Reset all power connectors and try starting again. If it still doesn't work, remove all memory and try starting it. If it doesn't beep, it's probably a bad board, not psu.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms on my optiplex 780 whilst trying to install new memory. Maybe try switching up your memory configuration, for example trying to start your pc with 2gb instead of 4gb.

(This would be a comment if I had perms to make one.)